# What is the right way to run a certain function on data taken from database once a week

Tags: database, scheduled-tasks

**Desciption :**

I have tables which hold all the information of up votes , down votes ,  post updates etc,

Now admin is the only person who can view the graphs and pie charts of the percentage of posts up votes etc after every 2 days gap.

In the admin panel I have a tab that shows the minified version of any change in the graphs after 2 days of data stored.

Now there must be a way to perform a function on the data taken from the table after every 2 days.

I am using PHP xChart library to make the graphs

**What have I tried Up till now ?**

I have tried to use `setInterval` in javascript but every one at stack overflow and other forms seems to disagree with this approach as it is *infeasible* ?? 
I am using mysql on phpmyadmin
any ideas what I should do ?

Comment: You didn't bother to tell us **which database you're using** seeing databases have their own mechanisms to execute methods in a timed fashion..

Comment: @Uzumaki Naruto - If you are using SQL Server for back-end then you can use **SQL Job Schedule** for accomplish you task.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to do it client-side. What if the client application gets closed?

Comment: Are you using linux or windows? The best approach would be to set a php file that runs with a windows task schedule (or crontab job - if linux). I can write you down steps if you would like

Comment: Yes ! I am using windows

Comment: MySQL has Event Scheduler. Google it, check the syntax, use it.